# Extracting a single attribute from multiple attributes within an anchor tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, attributes, anchor

As per the title, this is my code:

```
import bs4
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/predefined/undervalued_growth_stocks"

loadpage = uReq(my_url)
showloadpage = loadpage.read()
loadpage.close()

soupit = soup(showloadpage, "html.parser")

#the regex works - returns all of the "tr" tags, i.e. containers
containers = soupit.findAll("tr", {"class" : re.compile("data-row.*")})


for container in containers:
    container.findAll("a", {"class" : "Fw(b)"})
```

What I get as a result is:

```
[<a class="Fw(b)" data-reactid="69" data-symbol="AMAT" href="/quote/AMAT?p=AMAT">AMAT</a>]
[<a class="Fw(b)" data-reactid="99" data-symbol="MS" href="/quote/MS?p=MS">MS</a>]
[<a class="Fw(b)" data-reactid="129" data-symbol="NLY" href="/quote/NLY?p=NLY">NLY</a>]
[<a class="Fw(b)" data-reactid="159" data-symbol="ODP" href="/quote/ODP?p=ODP">ODP</a>]
[<a class="Fw(b)" data-reactid="189" data-symbol="FCAU" href="/quote/FCAU?p=FCAU">FCAU</a>]
[<a class="Fw(b)" data-reactid="219" data-symbol="RDC" href="/quote/RDC?p=RDC">RDC</a>]
[<a class="Fw(b)" data-reactid="249" data-symbol="ING" href="/quote/ING?p=ING">ING</a>]
[<a class="Fw(b)" data-reactid="279" data-symbol="FTI" href="/quote/FTI?p=FTI">FTI</a>]
[<a class="Fw(b)" data-reactid="309" data-symbol="BX" href="/quote/BX?p=BX">BX</a>]
[<a class="Fw(b)" data-reactid="339" data-symbol="FNSR" href="/quote/FNSR?p=FNSR">FNSR</a>]
```

What I am trying to get is the `data-symbol` attribute right now, but eventually I want the `href` too. I've tried a few different approaches now but with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the links you find for each container and get the values you want. `link` is a `dictionary` so if you don't want to use `get()` method you can easily get the value using the attribute names as keys, like `link["href"]`. 
Try `lxml` parser, it's a lot faster than `html.parser`.

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/predefined/undervalued_growth_stocks"

loadpage = uReq(my_url)
showloadpage = loadpage.read()
loadpage.close()

soupit = soup(showloadpage, "lxml")

#the regex works - returns all of the "tr" tags, i.e. containers
containers = soupit.find_all("tr", {"class" : re.compile("data-row.*")})

for container in containers:
    links = container.find_all("a", {"class" : "Fw(b)"})
    for link in links:
        data_symbol = link.get("data-symbol")
        href = link.get("href")
        print(data_symbol, href)
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thank you MD Khairul Basar.